# Multi-Project sln. Into their own separate slns

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What is the proper way to take a multi-project sln and create two separate sln's from each project?  They are all ready created I just need to separate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click project in solution > remove

Create new project > right click > add > existing project > find project in file system

If the projects depend on each other, you'll need to either:

- Compile and add them to each other as a binary, or
- Don't separate the solution in the first place

Answer (score 0):

If you clode the multi-project solution and open the individual projects, a solution (contining just that project) will be created.  If you compile the project you will be prompted whether you want to save the solution.